# Bytes message argument error

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I can't figure out what the 'bytes' method is complaining about. In the code below, i am trying to generate an authentication key for my client and i keep getting this error [1]

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

message = bytes("Message", 'utf-8') # errors here
secret = bytes("secret", 'utf-8')

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest());
print(signature)
```

[1]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "API/test/auth-client.py", line 11, in <module>
    message = bytes("Message", 'utf-8')
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: `bytes()` accepts only one string argument. Try just `message = bytes("Message")` and `secret = bytes("secret")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bytes()` in Python 2.x is the same as `str()` and it accepts only one string argument.

Use just `message = "Message"` and `secret = "secret"`. You don't even need `bytes()` here.

Answer (score 6):

The likely reason you encountered this problem is the code you were using was written for Python 3.x and you executed it under Python 2.x.

*I know someone has already partially stated this, but I thought it might be helpful to make it clearer to people new to Python who may not realize why the 'utf-8' argument was being used as the person asking the question noted that they did not know what the argument was for.*

*Anyone who comes here may find that useful in understanding why there was an argument of 'utf-8'.*

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

message = bytes("Message")
secret = bytes("secret")

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
print(signature)
```