# why i didn't get any error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, server, client

I want to know the Exception name that happen when a server have connection with a client in specific port, and another client wanna make a connection to server from that port ...

So i make server, client1 and client2 but when server and client1 are connected together and i run client3 amazingly without any error they all continue running.

I wanto to know why i didn`t get any error?
what's exactly the role of '1' in this line: serverSocket.listen(1)

This is server code:

```
import socket
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', 80))
print("Host=%s" %str(serverSocket.getsockname()))
serverSocket.listen(1)
clientSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
data = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print("from Client:%s "%str(addr))
print("\n data:%s "%str(data.decode("utf-8")))
#consciously i didn't close the the sockets
```

client1:

```
import socket
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 80
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(bytes("test code", 'utf-8'))
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print(type(data))
s.close()
```

client2

```
import socket
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 80
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(bytes("test3", 'utf-8'))
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print(type(data))
s.close()
```

sth else,why when i run client2, the server didn`t show any message that got connection from it, like:

```
Got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 64358)
```

Comment: is client2 really connecting to `127.0.0.2` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @SimonFraser srry that was my fault, it is local ...

Comment: The `listen(1)` may be why you're not getting an error. It's the backlog - so for example your server is talking to client1, and the waiting line to talk to the server is allowed to be length 1, so client2 is waiting in line, but the connection is never `accept()`ed because that part of the server is not in a loop.

Comment: does backlog have some time limit ??? if not,you mean i can get error when i try to connect three client to my server ???

Comment: @SimonFraser can i set backlog to zero ?

Comment: You can - replace the 1 with a 0, so `listen(0)`

Comment: @SimonFraser listen(0) was reasonable, but when I use it, again didn't get any error ...

Comment: @SimonFraser could you tell me the reason of why accept() should be in loop?

Comment: `accept` will accept just one connection, you need to `accept` every connection you want to receive

Answer (score 0):

The code of `client1` fails with error:

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

It's because that `bytes` in `python 2` is the same as `str` and it accepts only one string argument, credit goes to [`alecxe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18553283/503099).

Comment: the reason that i put a func to convert binary to str and conversely was that without it, i got compilation error. I`m just looking for a connection error ...