# Python string takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, steganography

I'm using the [stegano](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Stegano) module for a project. Stegano is programmed in python3 and my project is python2. My program throws an error: *Type: Exceptions Error, Python string takes at most 1 argument (2 given)* on line 41 of the module:

```
from base64 import b64encode
    if secret_file != None:
        with open(secret_file, "r") as f:
            secret_message = f.read()
    text = compress(b64encode(secret_message))
    img = Image.open(input_image_file) # line 41
    if "exif" in img.info:
        exif_dict = piexif.load(img.info["exif"])
    else:
        exif_dict = {}
        exif_dict["0th"] = {}
    exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.ImageDescription] = text
```

I found [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553214/bytes-message-argument-error), but I don't see how it applies to here since bytes has been completely removed.

EDIT: Stacktrace-
[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Comment: Please add full stacktrace, as I suspect it might error  on  a different line, not the ppen method of the Image class ... Maybe all needed imports could also be great in case one wants to help by trying variations. Thanks

Comment: That library supports python 2.7 and 3.4+.

Comment: I know it does... I'm still running into an error...